# Search word in array using regex and in_array()

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have array list like:

```
$arrval[0] = "fulanah bin fulan";
$arrval[1] = "joko bin dodo";
$arrval[3] = "mabhok bin jahannam";
```

Then, i want to use

> in_array()

Or something like that, for search an array with some words, for example using only word "joko". So if found in array list it will return **true**.

Do i have to use regex?, if so, how is its pattern and usage in function in_array () ?, thanks.

Comment: Merge 3 arrays and chunk array with space  and add into separate array items and then use `in_array()`

Comment: @DeadManAlive can we do this in one line ?, like inside `in_array()` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `in_array`, `preg_grep` could handle array well. Try this:

```
<?php
$arrval[0] = "fulanah bin fulan";
$arrval[1] = "joko bin dodo";
$arrval[2] = "mabhok bin jahannam";

$search_word="joko";
var_dump(preg_grep("/$search_word/",$arrval));
$search_word="test";
var_dump(preg_grep("/$search_word/",$arrval));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with `in_array()`. But you can use [preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

```
$arrval[0] = "fulanah bin fulan";
$arrval[1] = "joko bin dodo";
$arrval[3] = "mabhok bin jahannam";

var_dump(preg_grep ('/\bjoko\b/', $arrval));
```

Then you can `return`

```
$result = preg_grep ('/\bjoko\b/', $arrval);
return !empty($result);
```

**Output**

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(13) "joko bin dodo"
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/941671)